# How do you deal with a gap between vanity and wall?

Tags: bathroom, caulking, gap, vanity

I glued in the vanity backsplash, and I used a tad too much glue so it doesn't sit tight against the wall.  Furthermore the wall is not straight and even when I lined it up before gluing, there was a gap in places.

I would estimate the gap size at 1/8" max.

It's not the biggest deal, but it's annoying, and as you can see, a tiny bit of drywall fell into it (indicating that it may collect junk in the future).  How would you recommend dealing with this?  I could use a tiny bead of silicone caulk, but I'm not sure how that'll look, and undoing that will be annoying.[image: gap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A semi-flexible trim such as a real wood or PVC quarter-round could be nailed to the wall, following its contour and concealing the gap. Because this is a wet area, definitely don't use an MDF type trim.

If not trim, then caulk. Silicone caulks usually aren't paintable but latex caulks are. A bead of latex caulk painted with leftovers of the wall paint might be less noticeable than the dark gap with dust and crumbs collecting in it.